# Play Framework's Activator fails to compile project for the second time

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I run the "activator ui" command and choose the "play-scala-intro".
Activator clones new project, compiles it and runs it without any problems.

Then I hit "Start compiling" button again and Activator logs:

```
Waiting for threads to exit or System.exit to be called.
Waiting for thread run-main-0 to terminate.
Interrupting thread run-main-0
Interrupted run-main-0
Thread run-main-0 exited.
Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
Sandboxed run complete..
Nonzero exit code: -1
(echo:run) Nonzero exit code: -1
Run complete.
```

Compilaction fails and it is impossible to run the demo again.
Even after restarting the activator I obtain the same results.

What I am doing wrong? How to fix that?

Kind regards
Kamil

Comment: Can you do a clean? Are there any pid files you can delete?

Comment: When I remove every .sbt, .ivy2 and .activator folder and I run it clean, then it works for the first time but fails every time after.
Removing the PID file manually doesn't change anything.